# SSL broken encryption in Firefox

Tags: centos, ssl

I have an SSL wildcard certificate installed on a number of servers, in Firefox the padlock is broken citing a issue with encryption.

```
Broken Encryption (TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 128 bit keys, TLS 1.0)
```

All other browsers have no issue with the certificate.

This is my Apache config:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL -SSLv3 -SSLv2 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite RC4:HIGH:!ADH:!DH:!AES:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:!3DES
```

I can't use TLS 1.1 as centos doesn't support it.

The cert is actually 256bits, so I think I need to alter the cipher suite to force a 256bits cipher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use RC4 in any cipher suite, as this cryptographic protocol is considered broken and has been [prohibited by the IETF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7465/).

Thus the warning from firefox on the use of a RC4-based cipher suite.

You should update your SSLCipherSuite to something such as

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!RC4:!ADH:!DH:!AES:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:!3DES
```

Even better would be to take one of the SSLCipherSuite example from [this list](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS), depending on what your server actually supports (I guess the intermediate one, but I could be wrong).